# Conditionally prevent Django join with chained serializers

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I have a serializer, `requirementsSerializer`, that fetches two chained tables, `comments` and `relatedfiles`. In my `views.py`, I know how to conditionally filter for the related tables if the user is logged in. What I am confused about, is how to exclude/prevent the chaining/joining if a user is NOT logged in. Right now, it returns the entire set of `relatedfiles`, for all users, if the user is not logged in, which is obviously a security issue. I know I could make a second serializer that doesn't join the other tables, but that does not seem efficient or clean.

// serializers.py

```
class RequirementsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    relatedfiles_set = RelatedFileSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    comments_set = CommentsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Controls
        fields = ('id', 'sorting_id', 'relatedfiles_set', 'comments_set', 'requirement', 'requirement_section', 'requirement_subsection', 'requirement_version')
```

// views.py

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    queryset = Controls.objects.filter(requirement_version=requirement).filter(relatedfiles__team=request.user.team_id)
else:
    queryset = Controls.objects.filter(requirement_version=requirement)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create another Serializer you can allow dynamically modifying its fields like in the example below.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#example

```
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""
A ModelSerializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
controls which fields should be displayed.
"""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
    fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

    # Instantiate the superclass normally
    super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if fields is not None:
        # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
        allowed = set(fields)
        existing = set(self.fields)
        for field_name in existing - allowed:
            self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

Now you can pass a subset of fields if the user is not authenticated

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    RequirementsSerializer(instance)
else:
    RequirementsSerializer(instance, fields=('comments_set',)) # excluding relatedfiles_set
```

If you are not explicitly instantiating the Serializer you can override the view's `get_serializer` method which should return a Serializer instance and put the conditional there.

```
def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Return the serializer instance that should be used for validating and
    deserializing input, and for serializing output.
    """
    serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
    kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()

    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        kwargs['fields'] = ('comments_set',)

    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```